# TextBox stretch per content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to make my textbox stretch via it's content ?

```
<TextBox  Height="39" Width="180" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="ProductNametextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Text="{Binding Path=ProductName}"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: @Haris Hasan , user not typing anything I am presenting data from Text="{Binding Path=ProductName}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<TextBox  Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="ProductNametextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Text="{Binding Path=ProductName}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to let the user edit the text, consider to use a TextBlock instead. If you do not specify a size for it, it will take just the space it needs - while the container might still decide to stretch it.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `Width` there will be no automatic sizing at all, if unset mostly the alignment matters. If you set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch` it will take up all available space in that direction, every other value will make the control size to content and place it at the respective position.